# Does Attack Up on Bow also affect the sword?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

If I have a bow that has Attack Up + 6 equipped, does this mean that when I use my sword, the sword also gets the attack up benefit?

Does it affect all other attacks I may do?

Answer (score 10):

No, weapons have a base attack stat. The bow's stat is modified by the Attack Up bonus, so the value you see in the corner is the attack amount of just the *bow* and nothing else